# what is the wrong with my update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

guyz i have this query in my php project and i dont know what is wrong with it can any one help

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$middle_name = $_POST['middle_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
$number = $_POST['number'];


mysql_connect('domain','username','password');
mysql_select_db('db name');

$query="UPDATE scout_cabs SET first_name = '$first_name' , middle_name = '$middle_name' , last_name = '$last_name' , telephone = '$telephone' , date_of_birth = '$date_of_birth'  WHERE number = '$number'";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
```

Comment: What is `number`? Integer or string?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: One thing wrong with it is that it's susceptible to SQL injection, though I doubt that's the problem you're actually asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check whether the variables are set or not. The query will not work if the variables are empty.

```
//something like
$first_name = isset($_POST['first_name'])?$_POST['first_name']:NULL;
//other variables as well
```

> If it does not work then, check your query in *mysql*
>   A bit of suggestion use  **mysqli** instead of **mysql**